# Cannot import Pymeshlab due to QT version

Tags: qt, ubuntu, pymeshlab

I have a problem on my Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS when I try to import Pymeshlab using Python 3.6.9 (or even Python 3.10.6) :

```
>>> import pymeshlab
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/home/anass/.virtualenvs/py3.10.6/lib/python3.10/site-      
packages/pymeshlab/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
from .pmeshlab import *
ImportError: /home/anass/.virtualenvs/py3.10.6/lib/python3.10/site-        
packages/pymeshlab/lib/libmeshlab-common.so: symbol qt_version_tag version 
Qt_5.15 not defined in file libQt5Core.so.5 with link time reference
```

When I type 'qmake --version' on terminal, I'm getting :

```
qmake: could not exec '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/bin/qmake': No such file or 
directory
```

How can I solve this error ? I was trying to find a command that installs qt_5.15 but I didn't succed in find it. Any help please ?

Answer (score 0):

This error is a bug in the latest  `pymeshlab` version which is `pymeshlab==2023.12.post1`. `libmeshlab-common.so` probably wasn't compiled properly in the latest version. The developers haven't addressed this issue yet. You can use the immediate previous version:

```
pip install pymeshlab==2023.12
```